# Swift timer method terminates the app early with SIGABRT error

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode10, xcode10.3

Below is my code for having a timer change a variable from 0 to 1, which results in a SIGABRT error when the timer tries to fire:

```
var timerToggle = 0

    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(fireTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    @objc func fireTimer() {
        timerToggle = 1
    }
```

I know others who've had this problem seem to solve it by placing the timer declaration within the `override func viewDidLoad()` function but whenever I do that it gives me the following error

"Initialization of immutable value 'timer' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it."

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Where do you declare this timer? How long this owner object is alive?

Comment: @Asperi as it currently is, what you see in the original question all falls after the viewDidLoad() method.

Comment: Please in answer variant of timer in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0):

> "Initialization of immutable value 'timer' was never used; consider
>   replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it."
>    This is just a warning not an error. You can still go ahead and initialise timer in viewDidLoad.

Comment: but then it fails to load the simulator

Answer (score 0):

If it is needed to activate once-fired timer in `viewDidLoad`, it should look somehow like the following

```
class MyController: UIViewController {
    var timerToggle = 0

    private var timer: Timer?

    deinit {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }

    @objc func fireTimer() {
        timerToggle = 1
        timer = nil
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, 
            selector: #selector(fireTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to access the timer anymore simply add below to viewDidLoad

```
_ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, 
                         target: self, 
                         selector: #selector(fireTimer), 
                         userInfo: nil, 
                         repeats: false)
```

Comment: That does fix the error but I'm wanting these timers for my ads. I can make it repeating or I can make several non repeating times (i know it's not the most efficient but I was pulling my hair out with the repeating timer).

Am I thinking this through incorrectly? Do other people use timers to avoid ad fatigue?